Why do PALs have higher speed than PLAs?
When considering speed I have learned that PLAs are much slower than PALs. As each signal has to propagate through same sequence of gates (in series) why there is a speed difference?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Conceptually it's the same logical structure — an array of AND gates followed by an array of OR gates. But the difference is in which array(s) are programmable.

PLA - both arrays are programmable
PAL - AND array programmable, OR array fixed
PROM - AND array (address decoder) fixed, OR array (data) programmable

The PAL is faster than the PLA because the fixed OR gates (with limited fan-in) are much faster than the programmable array.
It's also worth mentioning that development of PLAs essentially stopped with the introduction of PALs, so the latter also has the advantage of more advanced silicon processes.

I vaguely recall that enahncement mode NMOS was used as pullup-resistors (depletion mode NMOS in the matrices) and this meant higher static dissipation vs more modern PAL/GAL devices. But I'm not sure anymore. Is that what you meant in your last sentence?

@periblepsis: Not really. I wasn't aware of any PLAs built using MOS transistors at all. My recollection is that they were mostly based on early TTL technology, using two arrays of NAND gates. Once people realized that the extreme flexibility of the PLA architecture was unnecessary in 99% of their designs, PLA development stopped, and subsequent PAL development was able to take advantage of further advances in TTL and eventually CMOS processes.

I'll look things up then. My memory certainly has its holes. May as well see if this is just one more. Thanks.

Ah. Found a link here via the archive. It's old. But find there, "The main advantage of the PLA structure is that a very compact and space-efficient realization is possible in NMOS technology. Small self-conducting (enhancement-mode) NMOS transistors are used for the pullup-resistors, while a depletion-mode NMOS transistor is placed at each location in the AND- and OR-matrices." Confirmation of poor memory? Sorry about delay. Hard to find old stuff!!

@periblepsis: That's certainly true of fixed-function PLAs used as building blocks in more complex chips. (Although you would normally use depletion-mode transistors as loads and enhancement-mode transistors in the matrices.) These were used, for example, as instruction decoders in early processors such as the 4004 and 8008. I've been assuming all along that the question was about stand-alone field-programmable chips.
